# USB device detection problems: using Compact Flash card reader and QNX (Virtual Machine)

Tags: virtual-machine, usb-drive, qnx, qnx-neutrino, cardreader

First of all, there's a similar [thread](http://www.openqnx.com/phpbbforum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=12845&p=52688&hilit=PC104#p52688>thread) on OpenQNX posted years ago but the solutions don't really apply for me.

Having said that, I want to create an OS image of QNX 6.6.0 to put on a Compact Flash card. This card is plugged in an USB adapter which is connected to my host pc. I'm running Neutrino in a VM (VMware/VirtualBox) for which I enabled USB support. Generally, the adapter works fine under Win (current host) and Linux.

The (apparently out-dated) tutorial I was following stated to search for devices named `umass*` or `hd*` after connecting the USB adapter. But there aren't any (except for hd0).

See also "ls /dev" [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vqwD.png).

The processes `devb-umass` and `io-usb` are running. So I expect that the adapter is detected automatically.

Any suggestions what went wrong?

Comment: @SilentDownvoter: Could you give me a hint what I could improve about my question? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that I had to restart the usb driver 'devb-umass' (several times). When the card reader is already plugged-in during the booting the driver will not detect it autoamtically. Thus one has to unplug and plug it in again after the devb-umass was getting re-started. It also might have been that the Host Controller Driver (HCD) was set to 'ohci' instead of 'ehci'.
Everything is working now as expected.
(Thanks Tim from the OpenQNX forum! ;) )